# Are there videocamera which geotag individual frames?

Tags: video, gps, geotagging

I'm looking for a way to record live video with the specific requirement of having each frame georeferenced with GPS. Right now I'm using a normal video camera with a PDA+GPS that records the position, but it's difficult to sync both of these plus sometimes I've forgotten to turn the PDA+GPS or it has failed for some reason and all my video has been useless.

Using google I found that about two years ago a company named [Seero](http://www.seero.com/) produced such video cameras and software, but apparently the domain doesn't exist any more and I only find [references of other pages mentioning it](http://www.crunchbase.com/company/seero).

Does somebody know of any other product? I need to record this video in HD and have some way to export to Google Maps or other GIS software the positions of the frames in a way that I can click on the map and see what was being recorded in the video at that point. The precission of the GPS tracking is good enough as one position per second, intermediate frames of the video stream can be interpolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found software [DV mp5 PRO](http://www.dvmp.co.uk/) which claims to [export GPS metadata found in videocameras](http://www.dvmp.co.uk/menus.htm#exportmetadata). I exchanged some mails with the developers and they said that most Sony cameras with GPS provide the required GPS information in the video stream.

I also found the camera [GoBandit GPS HD](http://www.gobandit.com/overview.html) which says to track your position, though their product seems unavailable yet, so I don't know if the software would allow me to extract easily the GPS information.

I'll go with a GPS Sony camera and use DV mp5 PRO to extract the information I need.